# Password Protected page not asking for a password

Tags: password, bug

I have set a page to be password protected in the admin, but for some reason WP is not asking for the password when viewing the page.

It definitely isn't a plugin as I have confirmed the behaviour with the plugin folder renamed. I have been testing it in Chrome w/incognito.

The page is using a custom template, which may be the problem? No other templates I have looked at though seem to display any password logic.

Comment: Maybe you already have the password stored within cookies?

Comment: Either you entered the password once before and forgot, or your custom template isn't set up to handle password protected content.  It will be easier to diagnose if we could *see* the code to your custom template.  Please post it here.

Comment: The template is assisting a very complex plugin, the content of the post isn't actually loaded as it doesn't  contain the loop. In incognito mode there are no cookies passed.

Comment: @EAMann is the pasword logic required in the template? Or is it activated in the loop as that would explain it

Comment: @EAMann, you don't have to add any checks in custom template for this. WP will do this automatically.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz/@Steven If you're using a traditional loop, you don't have to check in the custom template. If content is loaded some other way ("the content of the post isn't actually loaded as it doesn't contain the loop") then you need to run a check. That's why I said we need to see the code to see what you're trying to do, how you're doing it, and tell you why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was simply that the built-in password protection does not apply if you are using a custom template that doesn't include `the_loop()`. Lesson learnt.